# Creating dynamic inside ngrepeat - every href value is the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-href

I am newer to angular/js. I'm using ng-repeat to repeat results (as list-items) from a webservice. I have to use some of the fields from the json results to create a dynamic URL to use on my webpage for each ng-repeat item. Everything repeats back fine except for my custom URL.

Side note, I am also doing pagination - with 5 list-items per page. This is working correctly.

controller snippet:

```
$scope.stores = response.data;
$scope.jsonSize = $scope.stores.length;

for (var i = 0; i<=$scope.jsonSize - 1; i++) {
    $scope.storeSize = $scope.stores[i].SIZE;
    $scope.empCount = $scope.stores[i].EMPLOYEE_COUNT;
    $scope.customUrl = 'http://test.com/' + $scope.storeSize  + ',' + $scope.empCount;
    console.log("custom url is " + $scope.customUrl);
}
```

webservice/json snippet:

```
[{"STORE_ID":"001","SIZE":1000,"EMPLOYEE_COUNT":45},
 {"STORE_ID":"002","SIZE":500,"EMPLOYEE_COUNT":25},
 {"STORE_ID":"003","SIZE":750,"EMPLOYEE_COUNT":40}]
```

jade snippet:

```
li(ng-repeat="store in stores | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" )
    .store-link
        a(ng-href="{{customUrl}}" target="_blank") Employees
```

My console.log returns the correct URL for each result. The webpage creates the Employees link, however, the href value for every result item ends up being http://test.com/750,40 - from the last result.

I have tried ng-click and putting the URL into a function. I have tried href and ng-href as well, without any luck. Am I not binding this correctly or could my loop be messing things up?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your `for` loop is overwriting `$scope.customUrl` with each loop. Make it a collection, append to it, and then use that:

```
$scope.customUrls = [];
for (var i = 0; i<=$scope.jsonSize - 1; i++) {
    $scope.storeSize = $scope.stores[i].SIZE;
    $scope.empCount = $scope.stores[i].EMPLOYEE_COUNT;
    var url = 'http://test.com/' + $scope.storeSize  + ',' + $scope.empCount;
    $scope.customUrls.push(url);
    console.log("custom url is " + $scope.customUrls[i]);
}
```

And the view:

```
li(ng-repeat="store in stores | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" )
.store-link
    a(ng-href="{{customUrls[$index]}}" target="_blank") Employees
```

What's probably better is to just add a property to your stores collection with the URL:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=$scope.jsonSize - 1; i++) {
    $scope.storeSize = $scope.stores[i].SIZE;
    $scope.empCount = $scope.stores[i].EMPLOYEE_COUNT;
    var url = 'http://test.com/' + $scope.storeSize  + ',' + $scope.empCount;
    $scope.stores[i].url = url;
    console.log("custom url is " + $scope.stores[i].url);
}

li(ng-repeat="store in stores | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" )
.store-link
    a(ng-href="{{store.url}}" target="_blank") Employees
```

Comment: Thank you @tymeJV! I used your second suggestion and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the store to contain all logic for easy viewing. You could obviously use the `$index` to look in different arrays, but that isn't a really logical approach as far as I am concerned.

```js
$scope.stores = response.data.map(function(storeData) {
  return {
    storeSize: storeData.SIZE,
    empCount: storeData.EMPLOYEE_COUNT,
    url: 'http://test.com/' + storeData.SIZE + ',' + storeData.EMPLOYEE_COUNT;
  };
});
```

```html
li(ng-repeat="store in stores | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" )
.store-link
    a(ng-href="{{ store.url }}" target="_blank") Employees
```

Ideally, you retrieve data in a service and transform all the raw data into models and simply use those models to populate your view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pjetr. I saw tymeJV's answer first and was able to successfully implement it.